# GKMatchMakerViewController memory problems

Tags: iphone, memory, uiimage, game-center

I am using GKMatchMakerViewController and I find that memory usage goes up by roughly 3 MB. Unfortunately it does not go down after I dismiss the viewController.

Anyone else experiencing this problem? I think it may have to do with the graphics which are probably initiated with imageNamed inside GKMatchMakerViewController... not sure, though.